# How to retrieve varbinary from a string data?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlclient

I am trying to write an application wherein I have a table that I export to a tab-delimited text file. I have a column that is of type varbinary(max) in the table.

I convert it to varchar which just drops the 0x from the varbinary string and stores it in the file. I run this select query using sqlcmd on command line and store the result in a file.

```
SELECT AuthorizationId
   ,Name 
   ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(85), [ownersid], 2) AS ownersid
   ,[ownerSidWhereDefined]
   ,[AuthorizationType]
   ,ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), [ValidFrom]), '') AS [ValidFrom]
   ,ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), [ValidTo]), '') AS [ValidTo]
from Authorization
```

Sample row -
72  Administrator   01050000000000051500000026761E2FEB25792C07E53B2B24060000        4   1

After the export is done, I am writing a C# application that would read this file and perform a sqlbulkcopy to insert the data to a table in another database. At this point, the file contains the correct value that I expect it to be from the table.

This is the code I run to the same -

```
  public class AuthorizationsFmt
    {
        public string AuthorizationId;
        public string ownerSid;
        public byte[] ownerSidWhereDefined;
        public string Name;
        public string AuthorizationType;
        public string ValidFrom;
        public string ValidTo;       
     }
   IEnumerable<AuthorizationsFmt> FileData = from l in 
                   File.ReadLines(file)
                    let x = l.Split( '\t')                        
                    select new AuthorizationsFmt()
                    {
                        AuthorizationId = x.ElementAt(0),
                        Name = x.ElementAt(1),
                        ownerSid = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x.ElementAt(2)),
                        ownerSidWhereDefined = x.ElementAt(3),
                        AuthorizationType = x.ElementAt(4),
                        ValidFrom = x.ElementAt(5),
                        ValidTo = x.ElementAt(6)
                    };
        return FileData;
```

After this, I convert the Ienumerable to a datatable, use sqlbulkcopy to insert data into a table. The issue here is that the conversion between the string to varbinary is not correct while doing the sqlbulkcopy.

The original value from the file now becomes '0x30783031303530303030303030303030303531353030303030303236373631453246454232353739324330374535334232423234303630303030' when I see in the database. Also, this value is the same for all the records in the table.

Comment: String is a terrible format to process and should generally be avoided. Indeed there is only one type that is worse string - raw binary.  | It is also confusing that you are using your own tab-seperated FileFormat, rather then good old CSV files, XML or JSON. With the exception of CSV where there are no pre-provided classes, they can deal with nearly any data oddity you might encounter.

Comment: You realize that what you see in SSMS when you select a varbinary(max) column is just a REPRESENTATION of the binary contents, and not what is actually stored in there. The storage is not LITERALY "0x30783031...", it's the actual binary values REPRESENTED by that text string. Converting to varchar(max) will actually truncate at the first zero byte (varchar strings are zero terminated). So you have a ton of problems with your assumptions here.

Comment: @pmbAustin I am sure I have a ton of problems here and trying to figure that out along with understanding it. I realize it is a representation of binary contents as I have dealt with this type of thing before but that was import/export with SQL. this is the first time I am doing with C# and seeing this issue

Comment: @DaleK I am not sure if the reference helps me here.

Comment: Sorry I see you are already using option 2. I expect varchar(57) is truncating it. Try varchar(max).

Comment: What are you expecting to see instead of `0x30783031303530303030303030303030303531353030303030303236373631453246454232353739324330374535334232423234303630303030`?

Comment: @DaleK the max size for varbinary is 85 and that's the same size that I am using. 57 truncates it

Comment: @IanKemp I am expecting 0x01050000000000051500000026761E2FEB25792C07E53B2B24060000 to see in the database

Comment: So to clarify, the correct value is arriving in your file? But when added back to the database its not correct?

Comment: @DaleK yes, that's correct

Comment: I suggest removing all the stuff in your question about how you create the file then, and show sample file contents, and explain that the bulk copy is converting the data. I think everyone has got hung up on the initial pull from the database, but as you say that is working. However I wonder if you do need the '0x' in front of the data for a bulk copy?

Comment: So, originally I was doing the second part of my problem using SQL itself and that's when I needed to drop 0x and convert varchar back to varbinary to have correct value in the table. Now, I am updating this functionality in C# and that's where it is failing. I myself am unsure if I need 0x while export to have the correct conversion. I can update my question though.

Comment: NEVER, NEVER, NEVER use encoding on binary data it will corrupt the data.  What you need to do with a byte[] data use following string results = string.Join(" ",data.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")));

Comment: Thanks @jdweng. Your suggestion to not use encoding made me take the other approach. The solution you provided also wouldn't have worked. I needed a byte array to insert back into the db using sqlbulkcopy

Comment: There is no such animal as "varbinary string". "varbinary" is a byte array and you should be treating as a byte array and not a string.  As I said converting binary (byte array) to a string should never be done unless you are using an algorithm that does not change or delete characters (like Convert To 64 string).

Comment: @jdweng Could you please post your comments in the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used to convert to byteArray and then insert into the database

```
  public static byte[] ByteArrayFromHexaString(string hex)
    {
        int NumberChars = hex.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        return bytes;
    }
```

Comment: I found this very good article that supports @jdweng's comment - https://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/30/hazards-of-converting-binary-data-to-a-string.aspx/